# How do you add Media Services to the IIS 10 Manager

Tags: iis-10

I would like to add Media Services to my IIS 10.0 Website. (The site is hosted on a dedicated physical server running Windows Server 2016 Enterprise edition.)

Here is an image that shows "Media Services" options on the IIS Control panel. I cannot figure out how to add these features to my IIS Control panel.

[Image Showing Media Services in IIS Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hWse.png)

Comment: Any particular reason you’re relying on a release of IIS that’s almost 4 years old now?

Comment: I am a small company and it is difficult and expensive to upgrade every year. My site is dynamic and also incorporates Microsoft SQL server. I run Hyper-V as well. The website is on a virtual machine. It is always a challenge to get everything working perfectly (ASP, ASP.NET, SQL, Security Certificates, FTP, firewall, etc.) If there were an easier and more cost effective way...

Comment: You cannot. IIS Media Services component is only supported on IIS 8.x, not 10.x, https://blog.lextudio.com/status-of-iis-out-of-band-modules-80a3af57c489

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LexLi said, Media Services component don't support on IIS 10. You can use [Azure Media Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/). It is more convenient and easy to use than media services on IIS.

If you insist on installing Media Services on IIS 10. You can try this:

1. Open Regedit > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp
2. Edit "MajorVersion" and set the "DECIMAL" value to 9
3. Hit F5 while in Regedit
4. Now go install the Media services.
5. Change the "MajorVersion" back to "DECIMAL" value of 10
6. Hit F5 while in Regedit
7. Close Regedit